# PHP Reverse Sort Associative Array arsort() Not Working?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array, reverse

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction for why i cannot get arsort() to work on the following please:

```
$d=array();
$d['y'][0]['year'] = 2000;
$d['y'][1]['year'] = 2001;
$d['y'][2]['year'] = 2002;
$d['y'][3]['year'] = 2003;
$d['y'][4]['year'] = 2004;
$d['y'][5]['year'] = 2005;

arsort($d['y']);

$i=0
foreach ($d['y'] as $value){
$i++;

echo $d['y'][$i]['year'];

}
```

It just echo's out in the order 0,1,2,3,4 etc... I can't seem to find what i'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: well ur missing ; in $i = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you make an error when you print.
By referring to a value indexed as $d['y']['5']['year'], the result will  always be 2005.  Accordingly, the foreach displays the years in ascending order. Try instead:

```
foreach($d['y'] as $value) {
   echo $value['year'];
}
```

and you will see that your array is in reverse order.

(Don't use variable $i in the foreach cycle)

Comment: I tried what you suggested above, but it just shows blank (with no data printed at all) when using $value. Using the $i returns the dates, but the date order stays the same regardless of using arsort().

Comment: try with foreach($d['y'] as $value) echo $value['year'];

Answer (score 0):

Riccardo pointed me in the right direction, I found that i needed to use:

```
echo $value['year'];
```

and not

```
echo $d['y'][$i]['year'];
```

As the $i counter was calling the index number directly rather than using the sorted array when looping.

Answer (score 0):

Since arsort() maintains the key associations, the reordered multidimensional array will have the zeroth element last and element 5 appearing first.  Using a foreach-loop could leave the code prone to failing to display the reverse sorted array, if variable $i is initially set to zero.  To avoid such an inadvertent error as well as improve performance and simplify the code, one could replace the foreach-loop, as follows:

```
<?php

function showData($value,$key){
    echo "$value\n";
}
array_walk_recursive( $d, 'showData');
```

[array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), as its name suggests, recursively traverses an array to find the data.   The callback allows one to easily access and display values.

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/kVamA)

Answer (score 0):

It's because arsort() will keep the key. You can check the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

So after arsort() $d is like below, but you print in a reverse way which make it like not have been sorted. Check the [live demo](https://eval.in/793547).

```
Array
(
    [y] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2005
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2004
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2003
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2002
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2001
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2000
                )

        )

)
```